# Cannot install or boot Ubuntu on an external SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, ssd

Devices:

```
LG gram 2022 16
intel core i7
intel iris xe graphics
USB: FAT32
OS: Windows 11
Other info:

Ubuntu ISO: 20.04-desktop-amd64
Rufus: 3.21
```

I installed ubuntu 22.04 on an external SSD and it booted well.
But I had to use ubuntu 20.04, so I tried to install ubuntu 20.04.
I made a bootable USB using Rufus and tried to boot it by USB.
I can see the GNU grub screen and there is a [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbICC.jpg) (ubuntu, ubuntu(safe graphics), install OEM? etc).
If I click anyone, my laptop shows me a black screen for a few minutes and is turned off.
I tried ubuntu 22.04 again and ubuntu 18.04, but they worked well ( Bootable USB, SSD )

I set USB booting sequence for first, security booting disabled, and fast boot disabled.

I think it conflicts with WSL ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, but it didn't work after deleting the WSL.

please help me.

Comment: Why 20.04? Typically new hardware needs latest Ubuntu to have the updated drivers & kernel. And since Linux is not supported by vendors it has to develop those all on its own. Then those changes have to be added to distributions. So new hardware often needs a distribution a year newer that hardware. Very new hardware may require user to become a developer and manually install new kernel & drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

I have to use ros2 foxy ( not other version ) and it work in 20.04

I know that I have to install new kernel and dirvers now, but I wonder why 18.04 worked on my laptop

Comment: @cjt, You might have better luck with a preinstalled system via [this link to an Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS) or more specially [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS#Compressed_image_file). You need not perform any installation, only extract and clone from a compressed image file to the target device (the external SSD in your case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, recent versions of Ubuntu support recent harware much better than older versions of Ubuntu.

If you need Ubuntu 20.04 to run a specific version of ROS, install it in a virtual machine running inside Ubuntu 22.04.

You can use Lubuntu 20.04 (rather than regular Ubuntu 20.04) in the virtual machine because it is relatively lightweight, and demands less system resource.

Comment: If I use a virtual machine on linux, is it different from wsl?
also I don't know why only 20.04 doesn't work but 18.04, 22.04 work.

Comment: Virtual machine is a complete OS unlike WSL.